# Writing a Nested shell script- Unable to pass argument

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, argument-passing

I am trying to create a shell script using another script.
Following is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$#
cat << EOF > /tmp/kill_loop.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do
    for i in "$@"
    do
       echo $i
    done

done 
EOF
```

When I see kill_loop.sh , "$i" is empty.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
    for i in "one two three"
    do
       echo

    done
done
```

I want "$i" to be printed as such in kill_loop.sh file so that if i execute kill_loop.sh, it echoes the value 'one','two' and 'three'

Comment: this looks like an exercise in "here"-file syntax.  and not a very productive one at that.   here's an alternative exercise:   write a function "foreach" which executes it's first argument on the remainder.  then this whole exercise becomes:    "foreach echo one two three"   not to mention  in the original code, even with correct syntax, the while true; do ...   never terminates?!

Comment: or if this was an exercise in killing a task run in the background, then you don't need a "here"-file to create a  'forever' loop?!  conflating two learning points in one exercise is never a useful approach.  pardon me if i'm incorrectly assuming this is an exercise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "outer" shell script is interpreting $i as if it were one of its own variables, which isn't set, thus it evaluates to nothing.  Try escaping the $ so the outer shell doesn't expand it:

```
echo \$i
```

Comment: Or put it in single quotes

Comment: Single quotes won't help. The `$` is effectively inside double quotes as part of the here document.

Answer (score 0):

here is the "foreach" function:

```
function foreach
{ 
    typeset cmd=$1;
    shift;
    for arg in "$@";
    do
        $cmd $arg;
    done
}
```

Comment: What's the point of quoting `"$@"` if you aren't going to quote `$arg`?

Comment: Leaving `$cmd` unquoted is also an interesting decision; depending on the desired semantics around how a `cmd` that consists of multiple words (or includes shell indirections or expansions) should be treated, it might be correct to quote `cmd`'s expansion; to use `read -a` to read it into an array and perform a quoted expansion of that array; or to go all the way and use `eval` (allowing even dangerous shell constructs to be used).

Comment: Also, why the `function` keyword? That breaks POSIX sh compatibility... and to what end?